# iOS Speech to Text From Video File not Synchronized

Tags: ios, swift, speech-to-text, sfspeechrecognizer

Trying to create a video captioning application. I am opening the video file using UIImagePickerController. Can convert the speech to text but the text is created before even said on video. I need it to be syncronized with the video.

How can I syncronize the text to the video and print it to console when it is said?

func processVideo(_ videoURL: URL) {
let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))!

```
       let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: videoURL)
    recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { [weak self] (result, error) in
        if let result = result {
            // Update the text overlay label with the transcribed text
            let transcribedText = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(transcribedText)
            }
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```